# Permission denied when executing brew cask command

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv, homebrew-cask

```
$ brew cask install alfred
Error: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-16
```

My mac system had been upgraded to 10.12. I didn't execute `brew cask` before, but I did use homebrew to install some command line tools. No idea how and why it will report error about permission.

I checked my system, under `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/`, there're universal-darwin-13 and universal-darwin-14.  Also, I use rbenv for ruby environment management. ruby version is 2.3.1

Comment: can you run `brew update` normally?

Comment: Yes, `brew update` and `brew upgrade` can be executed normally.